# Call Python Function with Opencv in Django

Tags: django, function, python-2.7, opencv3.0

I have a python function for face recognition. I am uploading image with django. and in django given to me a path of image. So i want to call the python function for send a path to function. This python function is making face recognition and return to recognition image path. So i want to call this python function in django. Then I can show as  in django.

My post method:

```
def list(request):
    # Handle file upload
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newdoc = Document(docfile = request.FILES['docfile'])
            newdoc.save()

            # Redirect to the document list after POST
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('list'))
    else:
        form = DocumentForm() # A empty, unbound form

    # Load documents for the list page
    documents = Document.objects.all()

    # Render list page with the documents and the form
    return render_to_response(
        'myapp/list.html',
        {'documents': documents, 'form': form},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    )`
```

list.html:

```
    <!-- List of uploaded documents -->
            {% if documents %}

                    {% for document in documents %}
                    <article class="one_quarter" style="margin-bottom:6px;">
                        <figure>
                            <img src="{{ document.docfile.url }}" width="215" height="315" alt="{{ document.docfile.name }}">
                           <figcaption>Adsız</figcaption>
                        </figure>
                    </article>
                    {% endfor %}

            {% else %}
                    <p>Resim Bulunamadı</p>
            {% endif %}
            <div>
            <!-- Upload form. Note enctype attribute! -->
            <form action="{% url "list" %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <p>{{ form.non_field_errors }}</p>
                    <p>{{ form.docfile.label_tag }} </p>
                    <p>
                            {{ form.docfile.errors }}
                            {{ form.docfile }}
                    </p>
                    <p><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></p>
```

When i was uploading image, This python function take to image path and test image folder path, then should return to image path of recognition. Then i want to show which image path returned.

Python libraries :

```
import cv2, os
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
```

and function definition in python:

```
def get_face_recog(path, image_path)
    ...
    return frimage
```

Comment: Could you explain a little more what you want to do?  Can you provide a sample of the template you want to use and what you want to get back?

Comment: Actually i have a python function as i said. I am uploading image with django. and in django given to me a path of image.
So i want to call the python function for send a path to function. This python function is making face recognition and return to recognition image path. 
So i want to call this python function in django. Then I can show as <img src="path from python function"> in django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to call a python function is in your *view*, not your template. You could do something like:

```
def my_view(request):
    image_url = get_face_recog(path, image_path)
    return render(request, 'mytemplate.html', {'image_url': image_url})
```

Then in your template:

```
<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ image_url }}" />
```

If you really need to call the function from your template, you could write a [custom tag or filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/).

You'll need to configure your `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL` settings, and make sure that your server is serving the directory that the images are in.

Comment: shouldn't that be <img src="{{ image_url}}">?

Comment: Also, maybe I'm overthinking it, but don't you need to apply a static or media tag so that it will convert from location on disk to how that URL is served via the web browser?

Comment: @Foon Yes, there will be some configuration required to serve the image. The point I was trying to make is that the best place to call a python function is the view, not the template.

Comment: How can i do this for post method ? i am uploading image then i can take a path of image, i want to send  image path to function, then it will return recognition image path then i can show  recognition image path.

Comment: Please update your question with what you've tried so far for your post method, and explain what the problem is.

Comment: i updated this question and i give to more information about my question.

Comment: If you have a document `newdoc`, you can pass `newdoc.docfile.path` to your `get_face_recog` method. I'm not sure it makes sense to do that in your post method at the moment, because you then redirect to another url.